# ASP.NET Core. Is there a built-in way to cache data per-service (isolate one service cache from another)?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I read a lot about caches in ASP.NET and it seems that there is no cache service I need, but may be you can help me find it.

My requirements:

1. The cache must be isolated per-component because I use the same key in different services to store different data.
2. It must support expiration settings like IMemoryCache does.

Why I need it? Because I have several services that request data from remote sources, and they all have to cache that data to show decent performance.

Maybe I don't get it and it's ok to use IMemoryCache, but I didn't find a way to isolate one service cache data from another service cache data. Of course, I can add a prefix to every key with the name of my service, but it's an ugly way to use it.

Comment: Hope this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks, but I read it and it's not what I need because I need to work with the cache service inside my services - I don't need to cache my http responses.

Comment: I don't think there could be default segregation,  as cache is common to application you will require some kind of prefix. Also there is risk in case of multiple servers you can get on one server and not on other server.

Comment: Maybe the ugly way you mentioned is the best way as I think different named key may be better for an app.